# Imagemagick: Remove blured background from a sequence of images

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I have a sequence of images {image_0001.png, image_0002.png, ...} from which i'd like to substract a blured background using ImageMagick.

The one of the source image.

[image: A source image]

It is its blured version.

[image: A blured version of the image]

To find a blured background and extract it from a source image, I execute the following command:

```
    magick *.png -auto-level \ 
        ( +clone -blur 90x40 ) -compose subtract -composite diff-%04d.png
```

But I obtain only one image and result is ugly.

[image: The ugly result]

Comment: You almost never want `magick convert ...` see stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

Comment: Try doing one at a time with `magick input.jpg  -auto-level \( +clone -blur 90x40 \) -compose difference -composite result.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I have thousands of files.

Comment: Use **GNU Parallel** then. Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26169406/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2836621+parallel+%5Bimagemagick%5D

Comment: Do not try to use wild cards for input to magick (or convert) and expect multiple outputs when you do composite. You will have to write a script FOR loop over each input image and do your processing that way.